# Join on Multi-join Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have multiple-join query through 6 tables and i need to get new column with last Year values from the same query. Due to common answers on forums the idea is right, but somehow my result find values only with the same year (if I replace it manually in conditions), but not the previous one....

What am I missing?

- Column names were translated, so I hope there are no syntax mistakes
- Purpose: MS SSRS 2014 Report > Compare values from Selected and Previous Year - e.g. 1/2017 vs 1/2016
- In original query I use parameters in conditions (year, year-1)

Query:

```
SELECT
  ,Table6_Date.DateCode
  ,Table6_Date.MonthX
  ,Table6_Date.YearX
  ,Table5.PK_Table5
  ,Table5.CategoryName as [Table5_CategoryName]
  ,Table4.PK_Table4
  ,Table4.Name AS [Table4_Name]
  ,Table3.Id 
  ,Table3.Ave            --Main Number Values
  ,Table3.Ots            --Main Number Values
  ,Table3.Favourability  --Main Number Values
  ,Table2_Country.PK_Table2_Country
  ,Table2_Country.Name AS [Table2_Country_Name]
  ,Table1.PK_table1
  ,Table1.FK_Table2_Country
  ,Table1.LongDate
FROM
  Table1
  INNER JOIN Table2_Country
    ON Table1.FK_Table2_Country = Table2_Country.PK_Table2_Country
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3
    ON Table1.PK_Table1 = Table3.FK_Table1
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table4
    ON Table3.FK_Table4 = Table4.PK_Table4
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5
    ON Table5.PK_Table5 = Table4.FK_Table5
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6_Date
    ON (concat(YEAR([table1].[LongDate]),'M',(Format(Month([table1].[LongDate]),'00')))) = Table6_Date.DateCode 

--there comes the problem part with "Self-Join"--
  --LEFT JOIN
  --  ( 
  --    SELECT * --i use columns namely, but for shorter example "*"
  --    FROM
  --    Table1 Table1_LY
  --    INNER JOIN Table2_Country Table2_Country_LY
  --      ON Table1_LY.FK_Table2_Country = Table2_Country_LY.PK_Table2_Country
  --    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 Table3_LY
  --      ON Table1_LY.PK_Table1 = Table3_LY.FK_Table1
  --    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Table4 Table4_LY
  --      ON Table3_LY.FK_Table4 = Table4_LY.PK_Table4
  --    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 Table5_LY
  --      ON Table5_LY.PK_Table5 = Table4_LY.FK_Table5
  --    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6_Date Table6_Date_LY
  --      ON (concat(YEAR([table1_LY].[LongDate]),'M',(Format(Month([table1_LY].[LongDate]),'00')))) = Table6_Date_LY.DateCode 

  --    WHERE
  --     Table2_Country_LY.PK_Table2_Country = 20
  --     AND Table6_Date_LY.YearX = 2016 
  --     AND Table6_Date_LY.monthX = 1
  --  ) LastYearTable
  --    ON LastYearTable.PK_table1 = Table1.PK_table1
  --    AND LastYearTable.Id = table3.Id
  --    AND LastYearTable.PK_table4 = table4.PK_table4
  --    AND LastYearTable.FK_table5 = table4.FK_table5
  --    AND LastYearTable.PK_Table2_Country = Table2_Country_LY.PK_Table2_Country 
    --End Of SelfJoin--
WHERE
   Table2_Country.PK_Table2_Country = 20 --(20=France) --
   AND Table6_Date.YearX = 2017 
   AND Table6_Date.monthX = 1
```

Preview Output (without my new Join)  (2017 And 2016):

```
DateCode    MonthX  YearX   PK_table5   CategoryName    PK_Table4   Table4_Name Id  Ave Ots Favourability   PK_Table2_Country   Table2_CountryName  PK_table1   FK_Table2_Country   LongDate
2017M01        1    2017            1   Print   4   Articles    160 100000  4000000 NULL            20  France  147         20  2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2017M01        1    2017            2   Media   8   Billboards  169 1000000 4900000   50            20  France  147         20  2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2017M01        1    2017            1   Print   4   Articles    161 200000  4100000 NULL            20  France  148         20  2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2017M01        1    2017            2   Media   5   Television  162 300000  4200000 NULL            20  France  148         20  2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2017M01        1    2017            2   Media   6   RadioXYZ    163 400000  4300000 NULL            20  France  148         20  2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2017M01        1    2017            2   Media   8   Billboards  168 900000  4800000   100           20  France  148         20  2017-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
----------- ---------   ------  ----------- ----------------    ------------    --------------  ----    --------    ----------  ------- ----    --------    -----   ----    --------------
2016M01        1    2016            1   Print   4   Articles    164 500000  4400000 NULL            20  France  149         20  2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2016M01        1    2016            2   Media   8   Billboards  165 600000  4500000   100           20  France  149         20  2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2016M01        1    2016            1   Print   4   Articles    166 700000  4600000 NULL            20  France  150         20  2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
2016M01        1    2016            2   Media   8   Billboards  167 800000  4700000   100           20  France  150         20  2016-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
```

edit1: typo Removed

Comment: Try `AND Table6_Date >= '2016-01-01'`

Comment: I would like to obtain Current and Previous Year in the same row, i had this done before with another project, but with all left joins, so it worked easily and fine. I tried to copy same logic, but unsuccessfully, so this is why i choose this type of logic.

Comment: Is the commented code what used to work, and what your trying to get to now?

Comment: no, that commented code is idea of join same querry as a new table and return column with same specifics, but previous year...if i set year in both select to 2015...it will return values(the same ones), if i set 2015 and 2016 it will return NULLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data you are showing us from 2017 and 2016 are intended to be joined in this query it looks to me that the problem relates to the `Table3.Id` field.

Assuming I've correctly read which headings go with which data, the two data sets do not match on that field and since your 'self-join' includes a join on that field you'll never return any matching data. I don't know your data or what all the fields really mean, but you may be able to remove this line from your join:

```
AND LastYearTable.Id = table3.Id
```

It looks like you have similar issues with other fields, at the very least `PK_Table1`. You need to join the two versions of the query only on the parts you expect to agree.

**Edit:**

By the look of things, I'd expect the join to be on:

`MonthX, YearX, PK_Table5, PK_Table4, PK_Table2_Country`

Making the join:

```
) LastYearTable
 ON LastYearTable.MonthX = Table6_Date.MonthX
 AND LastYearTable.YearX = Table6_Date.YearX - 1
 AND LastYearTable.PK_table5 = table5.PK_table5 
 AND LastYearTable.PK_table4 = table4.PK_table4
 AND LastYearTable.PK_Table2_Country = Table2_Country_LY.PK_Table2_Country
```

By the way, with this you could also remove the `where` clause from the `LastYearTable` sub-query.

Comment: As written you also have a typo: `PK_Table2_Count` should be `PK_Table2_Country`.

Comment: even if i delete this line, results are still NULLs ( typo removed)

Comment: To updated Answer: I assumed that, soi went through all Columns and  thats why I select the most important ones (identificator from each table)

Comment: thanks, that join works properly--.but it helped me find out, that values per months are not 1:1, but can be M:M so now i have connected 1row 1/2017 with 4 rows 1/2016, and its correct...now i need to figure out how to sum them per month and compare it in one SQL query, i'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your **`WHERE`** statement to

```
WHERE
   Table2_Country.PK_Table2_Country = 20 --(20=France) --
   AND Table6_Date >= '2016-01-01'
```

or

```
WHERE
   Table2_Country.PK_Table2_Country = 20 --(20=France) --
   AND (Table6_Date.YearX = 2017 OR Table6_Date.YearX = 2016)
   AND Table6_Date.monthX = 1
```